# Why is content disapearing in IE 7,6?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

There is a link to the page, that has this problem: http://www.klds.cz/aktuality

**This is how it looks in every modern browser:**

[image]

**And here is how it looks in IE7 and lower:**

[image]

Enyone knows what's going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clears need to be changed. I've had a LOT more cross browser success by using `overflow: auto;` than any clears. Try the below, it worked in my test.

Remove .clearer by commenting it out.

```
.clearer {
    /*CLEAR: both*/
}
```

Add a new entry to main.css to allow it to overflow properly

```
.news_main  .item {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I tested a copy of your site with the changes on IE7 and that resolved it.